# Shiny app - reactive data frame for multiple uses & delayed activity

Tags: r, shiny

I am creating a shiny dashboard with multiple KPI value boxes. I won't paste in the whole server/code (>500 lines of code), but each box is called using renderValueBox, I create the data frame "kpidat" to use (i do this for every box) and I use if statements to determine the color and symbol for the box. See example code below:

```
output$incbox <- renderValueBox({

    area_prev<-as.character(input$dynamic2)
    prev_region<-input$select_B
    kpidat<-sept[sept$area==area_prev & sept$region==prev_region,]

    if(kpidat$`New TB incidents`[2]>kpidat$`New TB incidents`[1]){a<-"arrow-up";b<-"red"}
    if(kpidat$`New TB incidents`[2]<kpidat$`New TB incidents`[1]){a<-"arrow-down";b<-"green"}
    if(kpidat$`New TB incidents`[2]==kpidat$`New TB incidents`[1]){a<-"";b<-"yellow"}

    valueBox(
        paste0(kpidat$`New TB incidents`[2], "Incidents"), "Number of disease incidents.", 

        icon = icon(a),
        color = b
    )
})
```

The code works ok, but I have two questions:

1. How can I create a single data frame that then gets used by multiple later functions (renderPlot, renderValueBox etc) without creating kpidat again and again? I assume is use `reactive()`, but I can't find any relevant examples or figure this out.
2. There is a short delay before the value boxes are drawn...during which error messages are visible (I think this is because kpidat is not available for a second or so). How can I delay the drawing of the valueboxes until the relevant data is available? I have tried a whole range of req(), if style statements with no success.

Any help at all would be hugely appreciated.

Andy

Answer (score 1):

Several recommendations:

- You can define `kpidat` as a reactive object that will update whenever `input$select_B` changes. To use it in other outputs, call it with `kpidat()`. Even if you use it in multiple other outputs, the expressions within `kpidat <- reactive({...})` will only be executed once.
- By wrapping your output calculation in a `tryCatch()`statement, you can return an empty `valueBox` if any error occurs in the process of rendering the actual output. [(Good explanation of tryCatch here)](http://mazamascience.com/WorkingWithData/?p=912) This will shield your users from ugly error messages while still returning a placeholder.
- Where possible, efficient programming is still your best chance for a speedup. Instead of evaluating a subset like `local_kpidat$'New TB incidents'[2]` 3 times, do it once and assign it to a temporary variable.

---

```
kpidat <- reactive({
  return(sept[sept$area==as.character(input$dynamic2) & sept$region==input$select_B,])
})

output$incbox <- renderValueBox({
  tryCatch({
    ## This will return if it can execute successfully
    local_kpidat <- kpidat()

    ## Only calculate these once
    foo <- local_kpidat$`New TB incidents`[2]
    bar <- local_kpidat$`New TB incidents`[1]

    if(foo >  bar){a<-"arrow-up";b<-"red"}
    if(foo <  bar){a<-"arrow-down";b<-"green"}
    if(foo == bar){a<-"";b<-"yellow"}

    valueBox(value = paste0(kpidat$`New TB incidents`[2], "Incidents"),
             subtitle = "Number of disease incidents.",
             icon = icon(a),
             color = b)

  }, error = function(e) {
    ## This, an empty value box, will be returned if any errors occur
    valueBox(value = "","")
  })
})
```

---

If lag time is an issue, you might want to consider switching from using a `data.frame` to a `data.table` (from the `data.table` package). For web-apps with large enough datasets on the backend, the faster execution of subsetting can make a big difference. (If you're dealing with <1000 rows in `sept`, this probably won't have a huge impact)

Without seeing your data I'm speculating here, but it seems like it might be possible to use `data.table`'s `shift` and grouped by to assign `a` and `b` as columns within `sept` one time on start-up. This could drastically reduce update time each time the user changes the inputs.

The example below is how an overhaul might potentially work.

These would be executed outside of your server code whenever you load your packages

```
setDT(sept) ## conver sept to a data.table
setkey(sept,area,region,date) ## setkeys on sept to order it properly, I assume there is some kind of date value here?

## Calculate delta for all cases at once
sept[, Delta := `New TB incidents` - shift(`New TB incidents`, n = 1L, type = "lag")) , keyby = .(area,region)]

## Add a and be as columns for sept
sept[delta > 0,  `:=` (a = "arrow-up", b = "red"   )]
sept[delta < 0,  `:=` (a = "arrow-up", b = "green" )]
sept[delta == 0, `:=` (a = "",         b = "yellow")]

## setk key on area and region for faster subsets
setkey(sept,area,region)
```

This would be in your server as normal

```
## New version of reactive kpidat()

kpidat <- reactive({
  ## Return only the last (most recent) using data.table keys on area and region
  return( sept[.(as.character(input$dynamic2),input$select_B)][.N] )
})

output$incbox <- renderValueBox({
  tryCatch({
    ## This will return if it can execute successfully
    local_kpidat <- kpidat()

    valueBox(value = paste0(local_kpidat[,`New TB incidents`], "Incidents"),
             subtitle = "Number of disease incidents.",
             icon = local_kpidat[,a],
             color = local_kpidat[,b])

  }, error = function(e) {
    ## This, an empty value box, will be returned if any errors occur
    valueBox(value = "","")
  })
})
```

Comment: Great. Thanks for the help! I have now managed to create the reactive function to create kpidat just once as suggested. I will definitely also look into trycatch as I have not heard of that before. Thank you very much for the tips!